# How to validate a JSON schema with nested references

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON schema that references multiple schemas, using the '$ref' parameter whose schemas, in turn, reference other schemas.

For eg.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "xyz.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

where schema xyz.json is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "string",  "title": "Identifier"},
    "Xid": { "type": "object",  "$ref": "pqr.json", "title": "X Identifier"}
    }
}
```

Just for the sake of 
convenience, I've placed them all in a single directory and attempted to validate the schema using a library called [Ajv](https://epoberezkin.github.io/ajv/) but on compiling the schema I get the error: 
`can't resolve reference #/event.json from id`.

How can I possibly validate such a JSON schema? My goal is to create a single JavaScript object model for all the schemas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Ajv, but from looking at the docs, this seems to be accomplishable via the `.addSchema` method. Add all partial schemas like this (`fs.readFileSync` from node.js just for the sake of argument, in a browser it could be a XMLHttpRequest):

```
var main = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('main.json'));
var xyz = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('xyz.json'));

var avj = new Avj(main);

avj.addSchema(xyz, 'xyz');
```

and reference it from the main schema with the id you set in the second argument:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "xyz#"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you have multiple partial schemas, you can also add them all in an array, if you set the ids as properties:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "xyz",
  ...
}
```

From my experience with other libraries (the old [jayschema](https://github.com/natesilva/jayschema)), you might need to write `xyz#` (with a hash at the end) at least for the reference, maybe also for the id parameter.